# how can we receive message from IFTTT to a java code and vise versa

Tags: java, rest, ifttt

how can we  receive message from IFTTT to a java  code  and vise versa it may be restful webservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using IFTTT's Maker service it can receive and send web requests 
https://ifttt.com/maker. 
it gives you a key code to use and you either use a POST or GET request to trigger maker. The only problem is for receiving with maker it sends a web request to a public URL. I would recommend using something like google drive or drop box to modify a file and create a way to see that ifttt detected whatever you told it to do.

hope this helps

ps: if you want to see something some people made with maker:
https://www.hackster.io/ifttt/